# Can't export one simple image

Tags: rendering, error

I started learning blender by making text images. Made one last night and exported it, it worked.

Today I updated blender due to crashes and now I get a render that is 15% the model, 85% a pastel solid color.

What should i I do?

[image]

Comment: From your image, there is a cube hidden on your viewport (eye icon) but visible on the final render (camera icon)

Comment: I agree with Emir - you got a cube blocking your camera - objects hidden in the viewport will still be visible in renders unless you disable them.

Comment: OMG.. thanks! I'm new to this and overwhelmed; you were right!